# Direct upgrade from SharePoint 2013 to 2019

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, upgrade, 2019

I know i'm a little early.. But is there any information/speculation/rumors if it will be possible to migrate directly from SharePoint 2013 to 2019 via Database Attach method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guidance on upgrade to SP2019 has now been published on Microsoft Docs:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-from-sharepoint2013-to-sharepointserver-2019

Microsoft supported upgrade path is DBAttach method for Site Collections and requires an intermediate SP2016 farm:

> The upgrade scenario has not changed in SharePoint Server 2019. There is no direct upgrade path from 2013 to 2019. To upgrade to SharePoint Server 2019, you must upgrade SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Server 2016, and then upgrade to SharePoint Server 2019. Your databases must be at a SharePoint Server 2016 RTM version or higher when you upgrade to SharePoint Server 2019. Any database with a lower version will be locked and upgrade will not start.

Answer (score 7):

**Actually,** It's an early question, where there is no any published info related to the SharePoint 2019 yet.

**But** what is expected based on the previous SharePoint upgrade path process,

> There is no direct upgrade path from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint
>   2019. you should upgrade first to SharePoint 2016 then to SharePoint 2019.

**Meanwhile,**  what I am sure, the direct migration process can be achieved by using 3rd party tool like:

- Sharegate
- Metalogix
- AvePoint

**So,** let's wait ( expected `Mid of 2018`) to see :)

Answer (score 3):

Too early to respond, but i would recommend keep eye on the [SharePoint North America conference](https://sharepointna.com) which will be in May 2018. I am hoping we will get more information and beta version information.

But as per the experience and MSFT last migration practice, I am guessing, their will be no direct migration path from 2013 to 2019. You have to upgrade to 2016 then migrate to 2019.

otherwise you can use 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know , SharePoint on-premise 2019 will be available on the late fall this year .

Big Bets in SharePoint on-premises 2019 are listed in the following:

- Next-Gen Sync Client support
- Modern UX throughout the product
- Flow / Power Apps integration
- Other SharePoint Online innovations

You will need to upgrade to 2016 first. There is no way to do this skipping a version unless you use a Third Party Migration tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re already in SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint 2016, the good news is, your migration can be a lot simpler. You simply have to create a new farm in the new environment, copy your databases and update service applications, then upgrade your content databases and site collections.

This “simple” process can be complicated by custom solutions and integrations with other systems, so it’s a good idea to get a listing of everything that might break during the migration, and test your migration before it goes live.

Check out the below source link

[MIGRATE TO SHAREPOINT 2019 – TOP 3 TIPS](https://www.eswcompany.com/migrate-sharepoint-2019-top-3-tips/)

Comment: Do you think your answer is related to the question!?

Comment: well lets see , the question is about the possibility of direct migration from SP 2013 to SP 2019 probably via database attach method, and my answer as above and as per the link in it says it could be possible, so my friend  please read the answer and the link and you'll find it related. have a good day :)  @Chicago

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade directly from 2013 version to 2019, skipping 2016 will not work. Microsoft policy implies a gradual transition from one major version of the product to the next, without "jumping over".

Comment: Do you have a source for this answer? I know it has always been so in the past. But as technology didn‘t change that much from 13 to 16 to 19, i hoped it might become possible to skip one version. .

Comment: This is not a technical issue, but rather a marketing one. If you want, you can search for something on this topic on the Internet.